# Python - Screen-scraping and controlling mouse in OS X

Tags: python, macos, screen-scraping

I'm looking into screen-scraping and controlling the mouse in OS X for a hobby project.

I'm not looking for the most elegant way, but I need to be able to capture the screen every half a second or so.

I've found that I could use the `screencapture` command-line tool (`screencapture -w -W -i ~/Desktop/capture.jpg`), but I'm worried that it might not be fast enough.

I'm also looking for a way to send clicks, set the cursor position and obtain the cursor position. Sort of like what win32api provides: `mouse_event`, `SetCursorPos` and `GetCursorPos`.

I've found this sample code that uses the PyObjC library to set the cursor position, but it's always moving my mouse to (0,0) instead of the coordinates I pass it.

```
import objc

class ETMouse():   
    def setMousePosition(self, x, y):
        bndl = objc.loadBundle('CoreGraphics', globals(),
                '/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework')
        objc.loadBundleFunctions(bndl, globals(),
                [('CGWarpMouseCursorPosition', 'v{CGPoint=ff}')])
        CGWarpMouseCursorPosition((x, y))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    et = ETMouse()
    et.setMousePosition(500, 500)
```

Edit: I'm running Snow Leopard (10.6) if it matters.

Thanks!

Comment: At least for the screen scraping, PyQt4/PySide makes that easy; not sure about what sort of control you'd get for mouse position, that code may be the best way to do it for all I know.

Comment: Thanks for the PyQt4 link. There's actually a screenshot example that comes with it under `/usr/share/doc/python-qt4-doc/examples/desktop`. On a side-note, you wouldn't happen to know any library to send keystrokes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [autopy](https://github.com/msanders/autopy). Works in OSX, Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just screenscraping, might I suggest you try [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/)? It makes interface automation like child's play, and the scripting uses Python.

Comment: nice concept to use screenshots. How were your experiences with it?

Comment: Awesome. I created one to login to World of Warcraft in a single click (including Authenticator key) and various other "too lazy to click a bunch of times just let me enter all the info up front and have Sikuli do it for me" utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Would automation software like [ControllerMate](http://orderedbytes.com/controllermate/) help?

> allows you to customize the behavior
>   of your HID devices — keyboards,
>   keypads, mice, trackballs, joysticks,
>   gamepads, throttles, among others

Comment: Odd that this question hasn't been answered, but Quartz Event Services is the modern way to do the mouse controlling, and the CGWindow API to do screen scraping.  Both are C APIs, so from Python, you can either use PyObjC or ctypes to get to them.